# How to get bbox from geolocate?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, extents, geolocation

I am using geolocate to zoom to the users location. Afterwards I am trying to get the bbox of that area. However the geolocate function is for some reason always executed last, so I don't get any results (I only get `null`).

```
var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('vector');
var geolocate = new OpenLayers.Control.Geolocate();
map.addControl(geolocate);

geolocate.events.register("locationupdated",geolocate,function(e) {
    var circle = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
        OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(e.point.x, e.point.y),
            e.position.coords.accuracy,
            40,
            0
        )
    );
    vector.addFeatures([circle]);
    map.zoomToExtent(vector.getDataExtent());
});
geolocate.activate();

var bounds = vector.getDataExtent();
var coords = bounds.toBBOX();
console.log(coords);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Might take some time for the User's Location to be geoLocated. In certain cases, it might not even be possible to Geolocate the User. (For example the user might deny the permission for geolocation in the browser).

Hence you need to give a default location, and listen to the updates in the handler. Once the locationupdated handler runs, only then should you check for the BBox.

The following sample will show a good way of getting the user's Location: [Geolocation Example](http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/geolocation.html)